# StreamProvider with Firebase RTDB

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to utilize StreamProvider to see if there are changes in the friends of an user (i.e. if someone added/deleted the user). My current stream code is attached below. However I'm running into the issue ***A value of type 'Future<List<String?>>' can't be returned from the method 'getMyFriends' because it has a return type of 'Stream<List<**String**>>'***

Essentially for this stream, I only want to monitor the keys (in this case the userIDs of the other users) and not the value of the friends so the stream should be returning a list of keys. Any suggestions is appreciated!

[image]

```
  Stream<List<String>> getMyFriends(String myUserID) {
    return rtdb
        .child('friends')
        .child(myUserID)
        .onValue
        .map((event) => event.snapshot)
        .map((data) => data.key).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async*` and `yield*` with `Stream`s like so:

```
 Stream<List<String>> getMyFriends(String myUserID) async* {
    yield* rtdb
        .child('friends')
        .child(myUserID)
        .onValue
        .map((event){
          return event.snapshot.value.map((data) => data.key).toList();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm getting the error method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Event'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now!